# Install mac os X sierra fails with "not a valid volume mount point"

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I get "not valid mount point" error when trying to install OS X Sierra with reissued
installer with unexpired certificate (2029 expiration).

Answer (score 2):

The original installer's version is 12.6.03, while the reissued installer is version 12.6.06. Reissued installer has a bug which can be fix by changing 12.6.06 to 12.6.03 in Info.plist -file.

`sudo plutil -replace CFBundleShortVersionString -string "12.6.03" /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Info.plist`

After this fix the creation of bootable installation disk should work.

Info was found online but not very easily. I hope this will reach more people.  All credit to **[EricFromCanada's post](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/not-a-valid-volume-mount-point-cant-make-bootable-drive.1935673/page-3?post=28197924#post-28197924)**